# Fix Undefined variable and Array to string conversion in a str_replace function

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, str-replace

I got this function:

```
// load styles asynchronously - Transform stylesheet markup to loadCSS compatible
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'style_transform_loadCSS', 10, 2 );

function style_transform_loadCSS( $html, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle == CHILD_THEME_NAME  )

        $search = array("rel='stylesheet' id='$handle-css'", "type='text/css' media='all'");
        $replace = array("rel=\"preload\"", "as=\"style\" onload=\"this.rel='stylesheet'\"");

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $html)."<noscript>{$html}</noscript>";

}
```

It´s working but while debugging I see this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: search in /home3/me/public_html/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php on line 362
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in /home3/me/public_html/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php on line 362

Line 362 is:

```
return str_replace($search, $replace, $html)."<noscript>{$html}</noscript>";
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is you miss some brackets. In your example your statement goes only to the first next line and this is your `$search` variable. If your statement is false your variable is not defined and you'll get some problems in the next line where you replace your strings.

```
function style_transform_loadCSS( $html, $handle ) {
    if ($handle == CHILD_THEME_NAME) {
        $search = array("rel='stylesheet' id='$handle-css'", "type='text/css' media='all'");
        $replace = array("rel=\"preload\"", "as=\"style\" onload=\"this.rel='stylesheet'\"");
        $html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html)."<noscript>{$html}</noscript>"
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Both search and replace are now defined within the `if` statement and nowhere else. It would now throw two errors, one for each missing var.

Comment: I would assume that if the theme doesn't match, you would want to return `$html` (which would be the same as no str_replace). But that is just an assumption.